# Flexbox responsive product grid for all screen sizes

Tags: css, flexbox, cross-browser, responsive

I have a grid of products in which every grid have a width of 200 pixels. All I want it to work on all screen sizes.

My current screen size is 1366px. Moving to above screen sizes will left white space at right side.

`flexbox justify-content: flex-start`.

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile {
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="tile">1</div>
  <div class="tile">2</div>
  <div class="tile">3</div>
  <div class="tile">4</div>
  <div class="tile">5</div>
  <div class="tile">6</div>
  <div class="tile">7</div>
  <div class="tile">8</div>
  <div class="tile">9</div>
  <div class="tile">10</div>
  <div class="tile">11</div>
  <div class="tile">12</div>
  <div class="tile">13</div>
  <div class="tile">14</div>
  <div class="tile">15</div>
  <div class="tile">16</div>
</div>
```

[image: Flex]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? Of *course* there will be whitespace, because `1366` is not directly divisible by `200`. There will be `166` pixels left over. However, your images will *still* wrap to the next line, when there isn't enough space to contain them.

Comment: that is what I want to adjust boxes according to the screen. lets put width 166 and what if my screen size is 1920? 166x10=1826 and 166x11=1996. still there will be white space at right side. fixing width will add more boxes in row, if i put width in % it will remain 6 boxes for all screens with larger same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent is for your product grid to fill the horizontal width of the screen regardless of screen resolution, you could opt for a "fluid" grid.

A "fluid" grid will retain it's structure and "stretch to fit" the width of the parent container (or screen resolution), what ever that may be:

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile {
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;

  /* 
  Specify percentage based with causes tile width to update dynamically
  based on current width of parent. A width of 25% causes four tiles per 
  row.
  width: 25%;
  */

  /* For 6 tiles per row */
  width: 16.6%;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="tile">1</div>
  <div class="tile">2</div>
  <div class="tile">3</div>
  <div class="tile">4</div>
  <div class="tile">5</div>
  <div class="tile">6</div>
  <div class="tile">7</div>
  <div class="tile">8</div>
  <div class="tile">9</div>
  <div class="tile">10</div>
  <div class="tile">11</div>
  <div class="tile">12</div>
  <div class="tile">13</div>
  <div class="tile">14</div>
  <div class="tile">15</div>
  <div class="tile">16</div>
  <div class="tile">17</div>
  <div class="tile">18</div>
</div>
```

Comment: lets say 6 box in row... 16.66% is ideal... what if the screen size increase number of columns remain same.

Comment: Just updated answer to show that in action - I added two more tiles to fill the 3rd row as well. Hope that helps

Comment: lets say screen size is 1600px. Is it going to be the same 6 column box with wide boxes?

Comment: if i fix the item width to some value. upon stretch in browser it should adjust adding new box without showing white space... thats the main requirement. I have tried your example, it work perfectly in my case but when jump to large screen it keep 6 columns